# Concatenate ArrayViews (or sliceviews or SubArrays) in Julia?

Tags: julia

Is there a way to concatenate ArrayViews in Julia, that doesn't copy the underlying data? (I'd also be glad to use a SubArray, if that solves the problem.)

In the code below, for example, I want a single ArrayView that references the data in both `y1` and `y2`.

```
julia> x = [1:50];

julia> using ArrayViews;

julia> y1 = view(x, 2:5);

julia> y2 = view(x, 44:48);

julia> concat(y1, y2)  # I wish there were a function like this
ERROR: concat not defined

julia> [y1, y2]  # This copies the data in y1 and y2, unfortunately
9-element Array{Int64,1}:
  2
  3
  4
  5
 44
 45
 46
 47
 48
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/tanmaykm/ChainedVectors.jl ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly.  But you could roll your own type with something like:

```
julia> type CView{A<:AbstractArray} <: AbstractArray
       a::A
       b::A
       end

julia> import Base: size, getindex, setindex!

julia> size(c::CView) = tuple([sa+sb for (sa, sb) in zip(size(c.a), size(c.b))]...)
size (generic function with 57 methods)

julia> getindex(c::CView, i::Int) = i <= length(c.a) ?  getindex(c.a, i) : getindex(c.b, i)
getindex (generic function with 180 methods)

julia> c = CView(y1, y2);

julia> size(c)
(9,)

julia> c[1]
2

julia> c[4]
5

julia> c[5]
48
```

These methods may not be optimal but they can certainly get you started.  To be useful, more methods would probably be needed.  Note that the key is simply in deciding which member array to index into.  For multidimensional indexing `sub2ind` can be used.